# Read/write data into a file(text file) in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently ,I can save,delete,update,and modify the data and the changes are reflected in the local storage because my data gets stored in the local storage using this statement.

localStorage.setItem("Employeekey", JSON.stringify(this.registrations));

I ,now want to do the same operations into a local text file where the changes are reflected after adding data,deleting data,or modifying data.
I tried to use the file handling of Node.js using the 'require' but it didn't work since 'require' couldn't be found in the module.

Comment: node libraries are meant to execute in a NodeJS environment, on the server. Angular is a client-side framework: an Angular application executes in the browser. You can't just take any node library and use it in an Angular application.

Comment: can  javascript fulfill the purpose ?

Comment: Javascript cannot modify the local filesystem as this would be a massive security concern. Instead go for this one if don't have any backend https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d